Using T1 fontenc including lmodern, the generated pdf does not scale appropriately
I hope one of the more experienced users can help.
The following problem:
When I use T1 fontenc including lmodern, the generated pdf does not scale appropriately.
Result (depending on scaling, for some sizes it is as it should be) with T1 fontenc and lmodern:

Result with OT1 and default font:

As you can see, the A in "Material und Methoden" is shifted with T1 encoding in the generated PDF. The same happens in the continuous text when abbreviations such as LST are used, where the T is shifted slightly downwards depending on the scaling. Above a certain zoom factor there are no more issues.
Unfortunately, I have no idea where the problem lies. The document compiles without errors or warnings. I use the packages and class below, but even deactivating individual packages does not solve the problem. Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,final]{memoir} 
\usepackage{a4wide}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage[footnotesize,bf]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % scientific citation

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}

\let\printglossary\relax % Fixes conflict between glossaries package and memoir class
\let\theglossary\relax
\let\endtheglossary\relax

\usepackage[ngerman]{translator} % Load glossary translator, german

\usepackage[
nonumberlist,
acronym,
toc,                             
]{glossaries}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


This looks more like a rendering issue than a real problem. However, you should please post a minimal working example. So please remove everything unrelated (like ams..., mhchem & Co.), everything deprecated (a4wide), and a small but complete document which generates the pdf whose screenshots you show.

Thanks for the quick reply; here is the minimum example:
`\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{ruled}
\chapter{Introduction}
\newpage
\subsubsection*{Start}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{document}`
If I look at "Introduction" in the header, there is the same problem with T1, but not without (or with OT1 encoding).

Viewer problem. Here's the example:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{ruled}

\chapter{Materialien und Methoden}

\newpage

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\end{document}

With T1

With OT1


Thanks for the reply; it is indeed Adobe Reader; if I open the PDF with Edge or another PDF reader, the problem does not occur. I could have thought of this earlier, but still strange. Then I hope this will be patched.
This should have nothing to do with the discontinued step type 1 PostScript support from Adobe, right?
Thanks anyway
